# How to prompt second tab content while selecting 2nd option in dropdown

Tags: html, vue.js

Here i am trying to achieve a selection-based prompting tab content, If i will select template 2nd in select option. then if i will click on next then tab-content second should prompt, If i will select template 3rd in select option then if we click on next at that time tab-content 3rd must prompt. Please anyone can help me. I am struggling a lot to achieve this. please help me.

```
<div id="app">
    <form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete">
        <tab-content title="Personal details"
                     icon="ti-user">
          <select>
            <option>Template 2nd</option>
            <option>Template 3rd</option>
          </select>
        </tab-content>
        <tab-content title="Additional Info"
                     icon="ti-settings">
          My second tab content
        </tab-content>
        <tab-content title="Last step"
                     icon="ti-check">
          Yuhuuu! This seems pretty damn simple
        </tab-content>
    </form-wizard>
</div>
```

**vue.js**

```
<script>
Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 methods: {
  onComplete: function(){
      alert('Yay. Done!');
   }
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: this is the link for jsfiddle "https://jsfiddle.net/bt5dhqtf/97/", in first tab-content  we are having this select option "<select>
            <option>Template 2nd</option>
            <option>Template 3rd</option>
          </select>" and based on this i want to prompt the tab-content

Answer (score 0):

You can use `refs` and can use the `changeTab` method of form-wizard to change the tab.

```
<select @change="go" id="select-option">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select...</option>
    <option value="1">Template 2nd</option>
    <option value="2">Template 3rd</option>
</select>
```

```
go() {
    let index = document.getElementById("select-option").value
    this.$refs.formWiz.changeTab(0, index)
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me why we are using "formWiz" here

Comment: Its the ref name for the form wizard.

Comment: `<form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete" ref="formWiz">`

Comment: Hi yash your solution is helped me a lot and I am continuing with your solution. But I have one small issue I have two radio button step after category is filled. So because of radio button step i was unable to prompt the form.

Comment: <template>
<h1 class="post_adttl">Consumer</h1>
<input class="consumer_radio" type="radio">
<label>Personal Ad:</label>
<p>Personal ads can be posted one ad per month, which will appear <br> with "sale by owner tag"</p><br>
<input class="business_radio" type="radio">
<label>Business Ad:</label>
<p>Do you want to upgrade to business account to post more <br>ads per month</p>
</template>

Comment: Hi, Can you please update the code in the question?